# Getting tortoise svn committed task's taskid using sharpsvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

How Can I get tortoise svn's  committed task's task Id using sharpsvn to a c# application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a 'task id' in Subversion. Most likely your company uses 'task' as the label for the bugtraq issuenumber infrastructure. This is just a nice standardized UI over a value that is stored in the log message of a commit.

If that is the case, you should process the `svn log` output; which you can do via `SvnClient.Log()` and/or `SvnClient.GetLog()` in SharpSvn.

Comment: I have edited tortoise svn commit popover using butrack:url, bugtrack:message,bugtrack:number,Now there is a textbox displayed in the svn commit popover. On commit I have entered an Id in the textbox. I couldnt get the Id I have entered on commit to my C# application hooked with Tortoise svn.I have already used the GetLog() methode. Is there any way to get the Id I have entered to my c# application?

Comment: All the properties are doing is telling TortoiseSVN to prompt for data which will then be inserted into the commit message. So you'll need to parse the log for the revision to extract that data in your C# application - start by looking at the plain text of your log messages, then write a parser (probably a regular expression) to extract the ID.